# Как правильно настроить ui-router для angular1?

Tags: angularjs, маршрутизация, spa, роутинг, ui-router

Помогите разобраться с вложенным роутингом ui-router. Приведу простой пример.

Есть 3 урла:

/main

/main/apples

/main/oranges

Есть навигация из двух пунктов: apples и oranges. Она присутствует только на страницах /main/apples и /main/oranges и служит для переключения между этими страницами. Див с этой навигацией не должен перезагружаться при переключении между этими двумя разделами.

```
angular.module('fruits', ['ui.router']);

angular.module('fruits').config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider){

  $stateProvider.state({
      name: 'main',
      url: '/main',
      templateUrl: 'templates/main.html'
  });

  $stateProvider.state({
      name: 'main.oranges',
      url: '/oranges',
      templateUrl: 'templates/oranges.html'
  });

  $stateProvider.state({
      name: 'main.apples',
      url: '/apples',
      templateUrl: 'templates/apples.html'
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

  $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
  });

});
```

main.html:

```
<!-- Заголовок и текст главной страницы, которые должны присутствовать только на главной странице -->
<h1> Главная страница </h1>
<span> Содержимое главной страницы </span>

<!-- Навигация, которая должна присутствовать только на страницах /main/oranges и /main/apples и не перезагружаться при переходе между ними -->
<div class="navigation">
  <a ui-sref="main.oranges"> Яблоки </a>
  <a ui-sref="main.apples"> Апельсины </a>
</div>

<ui-view> </ui-view>
```

Мне нужно, чтобы на страницах /main/oranges и /main/apples не было содержимого главной страницы, но оставалась навигация. Сейчас на страницах /main/oranges и /main/apples и то и другое.

---

Спасибо за подсказку Grundy. Изменил код следующим образом:

main.html:

```
<div ui-view="fruits-main"></div> 
<div ui-view="nav"></div>
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

app.js:

```
angular.module('fruits', ['ui.router']);

angular.module('fruits').config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider){

  $stateProvider.state({
      name: 'main',
      url: '/main',

      views: {
        '': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
        },

        'fruits-main@main': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/fruits-main.html',
        }
      }
  });

  $stateProvider.state({
      name: 'main.apples',
      url: '/apples',

      views: {
        '': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/apples.html',
        },
        'nav': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/nav.html',
        },
        'fruits-main': {
          abstract: true,
        }
      }
  });

  $stateProvider.state({
      name: 'main.oranges',
      url: '/oranges',

      views: {
        '': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/oranges.html',
        },
        'nav': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/nav.html',
        },
        'fruits-main': {
          abstract: true,
        }
      }
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

  $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
  });

});
```

Но не решена одна проблема. Навигация перезагружается каждый раз при переходе из одного раздела в другой. Как быть?

---

apples.html

```
<h1> Яблоки </h1>
<p>Текст о яблоках</p>
```

nav.html

```
<!-- Навигация, которая должна присутствовать только на страницах /main/oranges и /main/apples и не перезагружаться при переходе между этими разделами -->
<div class="navigation">            
    <a ui-sref="main.apples" ui-sref-active="active"> Яблоки </a>
    <a ui-sref="main.oranges" ui-sref-active="active"> Апельсины </a>             
    <div class="animation"></div>
</div>
```

fruits-main.html

```
<h1>Главная страница</h1>
<p>Какой-то текст на главной странице</p>
```

css:

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.active{
  color: red !important;
}


@-webkit-keyframes go {
  from {
    left: 0px;
  }
  to {
    left: 500px;
  }
}


.animation{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;

  -webkit-animation: go 1s infinite alternate;
}
```

Comment: я не понял по картинкам, что именно не так. Попробуй сделать [mcve] как это сейчас выглядит и вставить в вопрос

Comment: Сделал. Постарался максимально понятно сформулировать

Comment: да, так хорошо, когда время будет напишу ответ, в двух словах - используй второе ui-view которое будет заполняться только в указанных стейтах

Comment: Если сам решил уже, можешь свой ответ добавить, с описанием что и как делал

Comment: Увы, не решил((

Comment: а что значит _перезагружается каждый раз_? как ты определяешь?

Comment: и добавь еще примеры маленькие разметки для _templates/apples.html_, _templates/nav.html_, _templates/fruits-main.html_, чтобы представлять, что именно там находится

Comment: Я добавил в файл nav.html див .animation и анимировал его при помощи css циклично для теста. При переходе между яблоками и апельсинами анимация прерывается и начинается заново.

Comment: ага и стиль тогда этот тоже добавь, для полной картины :)

Comment: Добавил css и выложил ссылку на пример.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что блок навигации меняется в каждом из стейтов страниц, пускай даже не то же самое.

Для решения можно ввести для этих страниц какой-нибудь абстрактный родительский стейт, в котором один раз выставить шаблон для навигации.

Это может выглядеть так:

```js
angular.module('fruits', ['ui.router']);

angular.module('fruits').config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider.state({
    name: 'main',
    url: '/main',

    views: {
      '': {
        templateUrl: 'main.html',
      },

      'fruits-main@main': {
        templateUrl: 'fruits-main.html',
      }
    }
  });
  $stateProvider.state('main.fruits', {
    abstact: true,
    url: '',
    views: {
      '': {
        template: '<ui-view></ui-view>'
      },
      'nav': {
        templateUrl: 'nav.html',
      }
    }
  });

  $stateProvider.state({
    name: 'main.fruits.apples',
    url: '/apples',

    views: {
      '': {
        templateUrl: 'apples.html',
      },
      'fruits-main@main': {
        abstract: true
      }
    }
  });

  $stateProvider.state({
    name: 'main.fruits.oranges',
    url: '/oranges',

    views: {
      '': {
        templateUrl: 'oranges.html',
      },
      'fruits-main@main': {
        abstract: true
      }

    }
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main/oranges');

});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.active {
  color: red !important;
}
@-webkit-keyframes go {
  from {
    left: 0px;
  }
  to {
    left: 500px;
  }
}
.animation {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-animation: go 1s infinite alternate;
}
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@1.5.9" data-semver="1.5.9" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<script data-require="ui-router@0.3.1" data-semver="0.3.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<div ng-app="fruits">
  <div ui-view></div>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="main.html">
    <div ui-view="fruits-main"></div>
    <div ui-view="nav"></div>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
  </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="nav.html">
    <!-- Навигация, которая должна присутствовать только на страницах /main/oranges и /main/apples и не перезагружаться при переходе между этими разделами -->
    <div class="navigation">
      <a ui-sref="main.fruits.apples" ui-sref-active="active"> Яблоки </a>
      <a ui-sref="main.fruits.oranges" ui-sref-active="active"> Апельсины </a> 
      <div class="animation"></div>
    </div>
  </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="apples.html">
    <h1> Яблоки </h1>
    <p>Текст об яблоках</p>
  </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="fruits-main.html">
    <h1>Главная страница</h1>
    <p>Какой-то текст на главной странице</p>
  </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="oranges.html">
    <h1> Апельсины </h1>
    <p>Текст об апельсинах</p>
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Grundy, большое спасибо) Это то, что нужно.